# Simple way to compare manytomany relationships? Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, pivot

I have a set of relationships that looks like this:

[image: Schema]

The users and agencies have a lot of data stored in them, in addition to the pivot tables you see there.

What I'd like to do is find the agencies or users that match the preferences of the currently logged in individual, whether they are an agency or user.

It's a straight comparison, so nothing fancy. But I honestly have no idea how to write the eloquent query to account for the pivot tables. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'm looking at something like this, which is understandably failing:

```
$loggedinagency = Auth::user()->id;
$match_user_agency = User::with('work_prefs')
            ->where('work_prefs', 'like', 
            Agency::find($loggedinagency)->work_prefs)
            ->get();
```

Edit: The relationships are declared like so:

User:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model  {


    protected $table = 'users';


    public function work_prefs() {

      return  $this->belongsToMany('App\Work_Prefs', 'preference_user', 'user_id', 'preference_id');
    } 
}
```

Agency:

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Agency extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $table='agencies';

    public function work_prefs() {

      return  $this->belongsToMany('App\Work_Prefs', 'agency_preference', 'agency_id', 'preference_id');
    } 
}
```

Work Preferences:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Work_Prefs extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'work_prefs';

   public function user() {

      return  $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'preference_user', 'preference_id', 'user_id');
   } 

    public function agency() {

      return  $this->belongsToMany('App\Agency', 'agency_preference', 'preference_id', 'agency_id');
   } 
}
```

Comment: I think it would help to have your models declared relationships posted

Comment: Sure, no probs. If it helps.

Comment: On first instance, it looks like you could have used [polymorphic relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations) for preferences, which could help to simplify things later on. Any specific reason you are facing it this way?

Comment: I'm still learning and polymorphic relationships are advanced territory for the insane and I only just learned how pivots worked last week? Basically that's the only reason. If a polymorphic relationship is the way to go, by all means make the case. I just need matches, don't really mind how we get there.

Comment: No worries! I don't think you *need them* by all means. But I believe that would help simplifying things later on. I'm not sure of understanding what you mean by matching preferences. Is it by preference id?

Comment: I'll look into them then. I'm trying to match the tag_id's yes. Basically if it's the same tag on either pivot table, it'll be the same preference.

Comment: Ok, what is the `tag_id` ? I dont see it in the diagram you posted.

Comment: Oh woops. It's preference_id. I'll edit.